# How to take multiple slices of a line from a file in python?

Tags: python, slice

Is there a way in python to specify multiple slices to read certain columns from a csv file?

For example, the data file can look like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,...col20
1,1,1,....,1
2,2,2,....,2
3,3,3,....,3
etc
```

Is it possible to have a command to grab the first 4 columns and last 2 columns?  I tried the following 2 ways but I was just taking stabs in the dark so didn't expect it to work.  One way gives me a ValueError, the other way gives me a TypeError.

```
for line in fileObj:
   date, name, time, data1, data2, data3 = line.rstrip().split(',')[0:4][18:20]  # got ValueError

for line in fileObj:
   date, name, time, data1, data2, data3 = line.rstrip().split(',')[0:4,18:20]   # got TypeError
```

If there isn't a simple way, can someone give me a hint to a possible direction to go to accomplish this?

Comment: Which version of Python? `first, second, *_, penultimate, last = range(10)` works in 3.x, but not 2.x. Alternatively, `[val for index, val in enumerate(row) if index in set_of_indices]`.

Comment: Have you tried using the `csv` module if you're reading CSV data?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thx for your answer.  the answer for 3.x looks cool and exactly what I need.  unfortunately, i'm erring on the side of caution and trying to write it in 2.x in case the server i need to deploy to doesn't have 3.x  =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track...

```
for line in fileObj:
   splitline = line.rstrip().split(',')
   date, name, time, data1 = splitline[0:4]
   data2, data3 = splitline[18:20]
```

or if you wanted to combine 2 lines:

```
for line in fileObj:
       splitline = line.rstrip().split(',')
       date, name, time, data1, data2, data3 = splitline[0:4] + splitline[18:20]
```

Comment: The downside of this is that you `rstrip` and `split` twice - I would factor that out.

Comment: sure...pretty easy to do

Answer (score 2):

using the csv module:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r') as openfile:
    reader = csv.reader(openfile)
    for line in reader:
        date, name, time, data1 = line[:4]
        data2, data3 = line[-2:]
```

This unpacks the first four and last 2 columns

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is the best library to work with .csv files in Python. For example, using the file:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3
```

To get the first 4 columns and the last 2, you just need:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csvtest.csv')
first_four_columns = df.ix[:,:4]
last_two_columns = df.ix[:,-2:]
```

I really recommend for you to take a look in pandas library:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html